# Does OpenSea support ERC-1155 (Fungible Token)?

Tags: erc-1155, opensea

OpenSea says it is a marketplace for NFTs, and it also mentions ERC-1155, as we know, ERC-1155 supports NFT and FT(Fungible Token), so, does OpenSea support ERC-1155 FT(Fungible Token)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OpenSea supports the ERC1155 standard. However, there are some restrictions:

- On OpenSea, ERC-1155 NFTs can't be listed on auction.
- You can only lower a listing price on ERC-721 NFTs, not ERC-1155 NFTs.

https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360063450733